# enviar un array desde javascript hasta el controlador de laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Estoy haciendo una consulta desde jquery hasta un controlador en laravel, el problema que tengo es que estoy enviando en total 5 variables mediante un `json`, una de ellas es un array pero el problema es que en el controlador no me quiere reconocer la variable en el WhereIN y me lo imprime vació, pero cuando voy a colocar datos estáticos, el wherein sirve correctamente, les dejare los siguientes códigos.

Este es el javascript, quiero mandar el `array_granjas` por json y cuando lo imprimo por consola esta bien, me muestra el array pero en laravel

```
 var array_granjas = [];

    $('#select_granjas').on('change', function(e){
        array_granjas.push($(e.currentTarget).val())
        console.log('value_select_prueba: --------->', array_granjas);
    })

    $("#elaborar_grafica_granjas_conversion_final").click(function () {
        var datachart = Array();
        var token = $("#token").val();
        var a_granjas = $("#select_granjas_conversion_final").val();
        var mes = $("#select_granjas_mes").val();

        var json = {
            annio_granjas:a_granjas,
            granjas:array_granjas,
            mes:mes
        }

        console.log(json);

        if (a_granjas == '') {
            swal({
                title:"No hay Fecha seleccionada.",
                text:'',
                type:'warning',
                showCancelButton:false,
                confirmButtonClass:'btn-warning',
                confirmButtonText:'Corregir',
            });
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
                url:'http://201.236.212.130:82/intranetcercafe/public/admin/report_precebo_conversion_final_granjas',
                data:json
            }).done(function (msg) {
               console.log(msg); 
            })
        }
```

aqui en el controlador de laravel es donde empieza a fallar

```
public function report_precebo_conversion_final_granjas(Request $request){
    $collection = Precebo::join('granjas','granjas.id','=','formulario_precebo.granja_id')
    ->select('granjas.nombre_granja', DB::raw('date_format(str_to_date(mes_traslado,"%m"),"%M"),avg(conversion_ajust_fin) as total'))
    ->where([
        ['mes_traslado',$request->mes],
        ['año_destete',$request->annio_granjas]
        ])
    ->whereIn('granja_id',[$request->granjas])
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('date_format(str_to_date(mes_traslado,"%m"),"%m"),granjas.nombre_granja'))->get();

    $arrayT = [];
    foreach ($collection as $value) {
        $arrayT[] = [$value->nombre_granja,$value->total];
    }
    return response()->json(['status'=>'success','data'=>$arrayT],200);
 }
```

pero aqui en el `whereIn` que ven no llega el array y me imprime vacio, pero cuando coloco datos estaticos me ejecuta correctamente, necesito ayuda con ese array.

Comment: y si solo haces ->whereIn('granja_id',$request->granjas) sin los corchetes.

Comment: carajo sirvio, no me habia fijado, debio ser por mucho estres al tratar de resolver, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Al paracer solo es un error de parametro en:

> `whereIn('granja_id',[$request->granjas])`

Ya que en el envias un array multidimensional, y solo deberias de enviar un array unidimensional.

Prueba con cambiando esa linea por:

`whereIn('granja_id',$request->granjas)`